# Wicket: Create control that swaps between a TextBox and a Label

Tags: wicket, wicket-7

I have a Panel that has an edit state and a view state. I need a control that swaps between TextField and Label based on the Panel's state. For example, in edit state the Panel would display as a TextField and the same field would display as a Label in view state.

This is very similar to the `AjaxEditableLabel`, but it is not the same. I am changing multiple Labels in my Form into TextFields at the same time.

In addition to swapping controls, I would like to continue to take advantage of `wicket:for`. Here is a proposed markup example:

```
<label wicket:for="firstNm"><wicket:message key="firstNm" /></label><br />
<span wicket:id="firstNm"></span>
```

I would like to be able to continue to add HTML attributes to the TextField. It would be possible to copy them from the span tag in onComponentTag. For example:

```
<span wicket:id="firstNm" maxlength="30"></span>
```

... could render the following in edit mode:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="30" />
```

I have also looked at the [ViewOrEdit control in visural-wicket](https://github.com/rjnichols/visural-wicket/blob/master/visural-wicket/src/com/visural/wicket/component/viewmode/ViewOrEdit.java), but I don’t think it will work with wicket:for.

Comment: do You know, TextField (and family) has setEnable (false), which is almost Label ?

Comment: Yes, I did. I thought about using just CSS before, but I didn't combine it with a disabled field. This is helpful, but I don't think it will work completely. I have to implement a solution for more than just a TextField. I need the same thing for a DropDownChoice and radio buttons. In the case of radio buttons only the selected value displays, so CSS tricks are not as simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using Wicket Fragment container. Define two fragments in the markup, for the `input` and the `span` respectively. In the Java code add Fragment with different second parameter depending on your conditions. The TextField and the Label should share the same model to show the same text.

Comment: This approach seems very close to the ViewOrEdit control (link is in my question). Is there something different that I am not understanding? Also, I implemented a pattern similar to the ViewOrEdit control and found that the swap works and my label turns red on error, but my required field indicator is missing. It seems that the ViewOrEdit control was closer than I thought.

Comment: The problem with my required field indicator is that I was setting required on the TextField instead of on the ViewOrEdit control.